# Laravel Homestead exception handling/pretty error message display not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, homestead

If there's an error anywhere in my code, such as in the routes file or a view, then instead of displaying the 'pretty' error message I get a dump of JS in the browser.

The error message is in there, but I have to hunt for it.

I'm using Laravel 5.8 in Homestead.

`.env` has `APP_DEBUG=true` set. I've also tried directly editing `config/app.php` to set debug but it doesn't work.

I'm quite new to Laravel so at a loss as to what to look at next...

Here's the first few lines of what gets dumped to the screen, please also check the attached screenshot below.

```
window.data = {"report":{"notifier":"Laravel Client","language":"PHP","framework_version":"6.0.3","language_version":"7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1","exception_class":"Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException","seen_at":1573633009,"message":"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: \/home\/vagrant\/pinyin\/resources\/views\/cards\/cards.blade.php)","glows":[],"solutions":[],"stacktrace":[{"line_number":251,"method":"handleError","class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions","code_snippet":{"236":"","237":"if (! function_exists(\u0027e\u0027)) {","238":"    \/**","239":"     * Encode HTML special characters in a string.","240":"     *","241":"     * @param  \\Illuminate\\Contracts\\Support\\Htmlable|string  $value","242":"     * @param  bool  $doubleEncode","243":"     * @return string","244":"     *\/","245":"    function e($value, $doubleEncode = true)","246":"    {","247":"        if ($value instanceof Htmlable)
```

[image]

Comment: How are you booting the server? Are you using artisan on port 3002?

Comment: Homestead, so `vagrant up`, then `npm run watch`, and browser sync proxies the URL that is configured in homestead.yaml, in this case `homestead.pinyin`.

Comment: I've just found that if I visit the url directly `homestead.pinyin`, then it works. But when using the proxy via Browser Sync at localhost:300X, it does not. Am I missing a config somewhere? The sites are set up in homestead.yaml, the the proxy URL is configured in ``webpack.mix.js `: ```mix.browserSync({
  proxy: 'homestead.pinyin'
});```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. In the webpack.mix.js file add the following to BrowserSync options:

```
mix.browserSync({
  snippetOptions: {
    rule: {
      match: /<\/body>/i,
      fn: function (snippet, match) {
        return snippet + match;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Solution from: https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/16#issuecomment-527260360

Found via: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29909